# PHP7 Adding a slash to all standard php functions php-cs-fixer rule

Tags: php, php-7, php-cs-fixer

Inherited a PHP7 project.  The previous developer added a slash to all standard PHP functions even for \true.  Is there any reason for doing this?

Some examples:

```
\array_push($tags, 'master');

if ($result === \true) {}

$year = \date('Y');
```

What is the php-cs-fixer rule to toggle this option?

Comment: Ok.  I understand the reason for doing it.  Which rule in php-cs-fixer for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As other answers have pointed out, prefixing global or built in functions and constants with `\` makes sure they are not over-ridden by declarations within the current namespace. An alternative with the same effect is to add `use function foo;` and `use constant foo;` lines at the top of your file.

In most cases, this is unnecessary, as PHP will fall back to the global / built in version where no namespace-local version exists, but there are a few cases where there is a performance advantage if PHP knows in advance which is being used (see [issue 3048](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/issues/3048) and [issue 2739](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/issues/2739) in PHP-CS-Fixer).

The option to control this in PHP-CS-Fixer is `native_function_invocation`.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the slash to make sure you are using the native PHP function or constant and not the function / constant with the same name defined in a namespace of the project.

```
namespace test;

function array_push($arr, $str) {
    return $str;
 }

$arr = [];

var_dump(array_push($arr, 'Hello World'));   // array_push defined in namespace test
var_dump(\array_push($arr, 'Hello World'));  // native array_push function
```

**demo:** https://ideone.com/3xoFhm

Another case why you can use the `\` slash is to speed up the resolving (as mentioned on the PHP-CS-Fixer documentation). PHP doesn't need to use the autoloader to find the function or constant declaration. So with leading `\` PHP can use native function without additional checks.

---

You can toggle this option on the PHP-CS-Fixer with the `native_function_invocation` (for functions) and `native_constant_invocation` (for constants) option. You can find an explanation of the options on the following page: https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer

Comment: Thanks.  it makes sense.  It is possible to override \true?

Comment: @Yada - As I know it is not possible (couldn't find a way). But perhaps with some extensions or special settings.

Comment: @Yada It's not possible in PHP 7, but earlier versions allowed you to do so using `define()`, like this: `namespace MyNamespace; define('MyNamespace\true', false); var_dump(true);`

Answer (score 4):

It could also have been because of performance.
When calling it directly from the root namespace performance is considerably faster.

```
<?php

namespace App;

class Test 
{
    public function test()
    {
        $first = microtime(true);
        for ($i = 0; $i <= 5000; $i++) {
            echo number_format($i).PHP_EOL;
        }
        echo microtime(true) - $first;
    }
    
    public function testNative()
    {
        $first = microtime(true);
        for ($i = 0; $i <= 5000; $i++) {
             echo \number_format($i).PHP_EOL;
        }
        echo microtime(true) - $first;
    }
}



$t = new Test();
$t->test();
//0.03601598739624

$t->testNative();
//0.025378942489624
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing.  That's a sizeable ~30% improvement.

Comment: Not since PHP 7.4. Native function call with or without leading `\\` is the same for execution time and memory usage.

Answer (score 2):

The above answer answers your first part, as for cs-fixer the options are:

```
native_function_invocation
```

and

```
native_constant_invocation
```

Answer (score 2):

Because of namespace.

Add `\` will find name from global space.

Here is a example:

```
<?php

namespace Foo;

function time() {
    return "my-time";
}

echo time(), " vs", \time();
```

You will get result like this：

```
my-time vs 1553870392
```

Answer (score 2):

Prefixing a native PHP function with `\` will specify that it is required from the [global namespace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php).

As of PHP 7, [*some* native functions](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/f2db305fa4e9bd7d04d567822687ec714aedcdb5/Zend/zend_compile.c#L3872) are replaced by opcodes if they are called using the FQDN.  OpCache is the hot topic when it comes to PHP 7 anyway.

By no means do all native PHP functions need this though.

For those who use PHPStorm, I recommend the [Php Inspections (EA Extended) plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7622-php-inspections-ea-extended-) which can inspect your entire project and find these optimizations for you.